# jQuery 3 different functions but any of the 3 updates all texareas not the one I need

Tags: jquery, onclick, textarea

I have 3 different jQuery functions setup for 3 different textarea's on my page. The way it is supposed to work is you pick from some choices and the choice you pick should then populate into the textarea for that choice. Problem is it populates whatever choice you make into all 3 textareas. Here is the link to the jsFiddle if anybody can lend an extra pair of eyes to tell me what I am missing I would appreciate it.

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PegWeb/F9K9U/3/)

HTML

```
            <div>Sale Locations</div>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="saleLocation" col="30" ROWS="4" ID="saleLocation"></TEXTAREA>
            <INPUT NAME="saleLocation_required" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="You cannot leave the field (Sale Location) empty.">
            <div style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px;"><span class="icon-location-arrow icon-large"></span> <span id="SaleLocationsLink" style="color:red;">choose a location</span> </div>
            <div id="SaleLocationsDiv" style="background-color:#fff; border:1px dotted black; padding:8px 3px;">
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Jane Doe
            P.O. Box 384
            Acme, BB 666666</a></pre>
              </div>
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Joe Blow
            123 Main St
            Someplace, AA 55555</a></pre>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>Terms Conditions...</div>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="termsConditions" ID="termsConditions" ROWS="5"></TEXTAREA>
            <div style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px;"><span class="icon-location-arrow icon-large"></span> <span id="SalesTermsLink" style="color:red;">choose terms/conditions</span> </div>
            <div id="SalesTermsDiv" style="background-color:#fff; border:1px dotted black; padding:8px 3px;">
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Net30</a></pre>
              </div>
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Cash Only</a></pre>
              </div>
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Net15</a></pre>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>Contact...</div>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="contact" id="contact" ROWS="5"></TEXTAREA>
            <div style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px;"><span class="icon-location-arrow icon-large"></span> <span id="ContactInformationLink" style="color:red;">choose contact information</span></div>
            <div id="ContactInformationDiv" style="background-color:#fff; border:1px dotted black; padding:8px 3px;">
              <div style="padding:2px 0px;">
                <pre><a href="./" class="SlidedownChoices">Mary Jane
            P.O. Box 69
            Up High, NY 90210</a></pre>
              </div>
            </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
            //code for slide down choices
            //code for Sale Locations Slide Down
            if ($("#SaleLocationsDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
                $("#SaleLocationsDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
                $("#SaleLocationsLink").click(function () {
                    if ($("#SaleLocationsDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
                        $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideDown("slow");
                        $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("hide sale locations");
                    } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
                        $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideUp("slow");
                        $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("choose a location");
                    }
                });
                //code to add the location to the text area box
                $("a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
                    //e is short for event
                    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
                    //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
                    var innerTxt = $(this).text();
                    //need to trim whitespace from the string
                    innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

                    var $obj = $("#saleLocation"); //replace this with textarea selector
                    $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');
                    //reset the sale locations slider
                    $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideUp("slow");
                    $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("choose a location");
                });
            }

            //code for Terms and Conditions Slide Down
            if ($("#SalesTermsDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
                $("#SalesTermsDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
                $("#SalesTermsLink").click(function () {
                    if ($("#SalesTermsDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
                        $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideDown("slow");
                        $("#SalesTermsLink").html("hide terms/conditions");
                    } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
                        $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideUp("slow");
                        $("#SalesTermsLink").html("choose terms/conditions");
                    }
                });
                //code to add the terms to the text area box
                $("a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
                    //e is short for event
                    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
                    //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
                    var innerTxt = $(this).text();
                    //need to trim whitespace from the string
                    innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

                    var $obj = $("#termsConditions"); //replace this with textarea selector
                    $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');

                    //reset the sale locations slider
                    $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideUp("slow");
                    $("#SalesTermsLink").html("choose terms/conditions");
                });
            }

            //code for Contact Information Slide Down
            if ($("#ContactInformationDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
                $("#ContactInformationDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
                $("#ContactInformationLink").click(function () {
                    if ($("#ContactInformationDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
                        $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideDown("slow");
                        $("#ContactInformationLink").html("hide contact information");
                    } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
                        $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideUp("slow");
                        $("#ContactInformationLink").html("choose contact information");
                    }
                });
                //code to add the terms to the text area box
                $("a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
                    //e is short for event
                    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
                    //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
                    var innerTxt = $(this).text();
                    //need to trim whitespace from the string
                    innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

                    var $obj = $("#contact"); //replace this with textarea selector
                    $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');

                    //reset the sale locations slider
                    $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideUp("slow");
                    $("#ContactInformationLink").html("choose contact information");
                });

            }
            //end code for slide down choices
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your selector `$("a.SlidedownChoices")` because it is registering 3 click events to all `a.SlidedownChoices` elements

You need to target the specific elements using `$("#SaleLocationsDiv a.SlidedownChoices")`

Try

```
//code for slide down choices
//code for Sale Locations Slide Down
if ($("#SaleLocationsDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
    $("#SaleLocationsDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
    $("#SaleLocationsLink").click(function () {
        if ($("#SaleLocationsDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
            $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideDown("slow");
            $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("hide sale locations");
        } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
            $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideUp("slow");
            $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("choose a location");
        }
    });
    //code to add the location to the text area box
    $("#SaleLocationsDiv a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
        //e is short for event
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
        //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
        var innerTxt = $(this).text();
        //need to trim whitespace from the string
        innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

        var $obj = $("#saleLocation"); //replace this with textarea selector
        $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');
        //reset the sale locations slider
        $("#SaleLocationsDiv").slideUp("slow");
        $("#SaleLocationsLink").html("choose a location");
    });
}

//code for Terms and Conditions Slide Down
if ($("#SalesTermsDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
    $("#SalesTermsDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
    $("#SalesTermsLink").click(function () {
        if ($("#SalesTermsDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
            $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideDown("slow");
            $("#SalesTermsLink").html("hide terms/conditions");
        } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
            $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideUp("slow");
            $("#SalesTermsLink").html("choose terms/conditions");
        }
    });
    //code to add the terms to the text area box
    $("#SalesTermsDiv a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
        //e is short for event
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
        //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
        var innerTxt = $(this).text();
        //need to trim whitespace from the string
        innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

        var $obj = $("#termsConditions"); //replace this with textarea selector
        $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');

        //reset the sale locations slider
        $("#SalesTermsDiv").slideUp("slow");
        $("#SalesTermsLink").html("choose terms/conditions");
    });
}

//code for Contact Information Slide Down
if ($("#ContactInformationDiv").length) { //does the div exist on the page
    $("#ContactInformationDiv").hide(); //hide the div if it is not already
    $("#ContactInformationLink").click(function () {
        if ($("#ContactInformationDiv").is(":hidden")) { //if the div is hidden then slide it down and change text
            $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideDown("slow");
            $("#ContactInformationLink").html("hide contact information");
        } else { //if it is not hidden then hide it and change the text back
            $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideUp("slow");
            $("#ContactInformationLink").html("choose contact information");
        }
    });
    //code to add the terms to the text area box
    $("#ContactInformationDiv a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e) {
        //e is short for event
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click event from going to a url
        //You want to append the text of the anchor link into the textarea.
        var innerTxt = $(this).text();
        //need to trim whitespace from the string
        innerTxt = $.trim(innerTxt);

        var $obj = $("#contact"); //replace this with textarea selector
        $obj.val($obj.val() + '\n' + innerTxt + '\n');

        //reset the sale locations slider
        $("#ContactInformationDiv").slideUp("slow");
        $("#ContactInformationLink").html("choose contact information");
    });

}
//end code for slide down choices
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sF7zH/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening, is because all your choice links are called: .SlidedownChoices

So if one gets clicked, it triggers all three functions and thus appending the result to each text area. Simply rename the .SlidedownChoices for each section to a unique class and it will work.

Alternatively you could probably roll all the functions into one as they are essentially exactly the same. You could use data- elements to trigger specific text areas and choices.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your click functions were having selctors that matched with all the links in the three boxes. Therefore when user clicks any of the options, all the 3 functions ran and changed the values in the respective textareas.

You need to use different selectors for each

e.g. for Sales Location use:

```
$("#SaleLocationsDiv a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e)
```

instad of

```
$("a.SlidedownChoices").click(function (e)
```

JSFIDDLE Link : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9K9U/5/)